# Simulate Click and take snapshot with Jest for React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to learn how to create units tests for my front end REACT application.

What I'm trying to test, is the output of a component, and then the output of the same component after a button has been clicked. (assuming that is possible).

I've seen examples where enyzme simulates a click, but I havent seen any examples using Jest snap shot feature.. what I have tried is (which does not work):

```
import React from 'react';
import TopNav from '../components/navigation/TopNav'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('Modal opens when when button clicked', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
        <TopNav history={null} showSignUp={false} />
    );

    let tree = element.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

    //manually trigger modal
    let instance = component.getInstance();
    instance.find(".login-button").simulate('click'); //Does not work, find not a function
    // re-rendering
    tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: The snapshot testing technique has more value when testing if you have changes in your UI like css. 

In your case there are some mistakes to run the `simulate`. You will need to use the `shallow` or `mount` fn from enzyme then you will be able to simulate a click

like `const wrapper = shallow(<TopNav history={null} showSignUp={false} />)`

and after that

`wrapper.find(".login-button").simulate('click')`

Comment: When do you click on the button, what should happens to the UI?

Comment: A modal opens. (I'm using ReactStrap) The modal is in a different component, so perhaps I should test both components separately (im just realizing this now)

Comment: you should have a test which checks, given the user clicks the login button ( `.find(".login-button").simulate('click') ` ) it should open the xyz modal.

You can do it by checking if the modal's property that states if the modal is opened or closed is exactly the value you are expecting. Could be something like a true or false